# How to implement Docusign in iOS and Android App with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, docusignapi

I need to implement a user to make sign in my app using DocuSign. I have implemented application using Xamarin.Forms. How to implement Docusign in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make user/signer an `embedded signer`. By adding `clientUserId` property in the signer node, like below:

```
"signers": [{
      "email": "signeremail@email.com",
      "name": "Signer Name",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "clientUserId": "12345",
      "routingOrder": "1"
    }
```

When you want signer to sign in your App, then you will call below endpoint

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient
```

with requestBody like below:

```
{
  "authenticationMethod": "Password",
  "clientUserId": "12345",
  "email": "signeremail@email.com",
  "returnUrl": "YourAppUrl",
  "userName": "Signer Name"
}
```

This API call will generate a URL which will have expiry of 300 seconds, redirect user to this URL and make user Sign using this URL.

More details for this API call are available at [EnvelopeViews: createRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/)

Example in different coding languages are also available at [DS Developer Center](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/signing-from-your-app)

Comment: I am trying to implement DocuSing using "DocuSing API's".
But I am suffering following issues.
1. I have implemented Authentication and Login api in Xamarin,Forms project.
But DocuSing API return content-type exception.

Comment: Hi, have u implemented this docusign with xamarin forms